# When chace clear not found 404

Tags: angular

i create new project angular
`ng new apps`

and build production
`ng build --prod`

in route

```
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
const routes: Routes = [
    {path:'', component:HomeComponent},
    {path:'about', component:AboutComponent},
];
```

but, when i'm hosting in localhost with xampp server when clear chace and refresh page error exception 404

**Not Found**

**The requested URL /office/about was not found on this server.**

Comment: use `hashLocationStrategy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We have two way for deployment angular application on IIS first is
>   using `Hashing Strategies` and another is using `web.config`.

Using `Hashing Strategies` you will get # in url. But It'll not break the url or display 404 error, if user `refersh the page or press F5` button.

**e.g.**
In Main module use `useHash:true`.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{useHash:true})],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

And second way without using `Hashing Strategies`. But we need configure it on IIS level and code level as well.

**Step 1:** On IIS level, you should need to check the url-rewrite functionality is allowed or not. if not then you need to download `rewrite_2.0_rtw_x86.exe or rewrite_2.0_rtw_x64.exe` for 86 or 64 bit operating system. And then run as administrator level.

**Step 2:** Create a web.config file and copy and paste the below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Step 3.** copy the web.config file and paste it where you application hosted on root level.

Comment: this work, but i get url **`http://localhost/office/#/about`**. how to remove # in url

Comment: @MarshallTelaumbanua for removing # you should need to remove {useHash:true} from above code and then create web.config file and write url-rewrite rules. For more info https://angular.io/guide/deployment and see IIS:

Answer (score 0):

Add a **.htaccess** file in folder with your compiled project.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```